# Can I remove the .xsession file and similar files from my machine?

Tags: xorg, files

Are the following files needed on my machine? (I want to remove them.)

```
    .xsession
    .xsession-errors
    .xsession-errors.old
    .Xathority.XXXXXX
```

I believe most if not all of them originated during my attempt at getting remote desktop working as I entered the following into the command line:

```
    cd /home/youruser
    echo “gnome-session –session=ubuntu-2d” > .xsession
    sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Comment: This is possible better advice than that given in the accepted answer: https://superuser.com/a/1013879/510928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.xsession` file are log files and can be safely deleted. They will eventually cycle out as the `.xsession` file will replace the `.xsession.old` file after a reboot.

I have never seen the `.Xauthority.XXXXXX`, but the `.Xauthority` is needed while you are logged in with your graphical gui.

Comment: Do you have some reference to attest to this. It would be helpful, when asserting that it is safe to delete files - even only log files - to show some evidence to give it authority. 

If it is utterly impossible for a system to fail because a logfile is no longer there (and some vital component is incapable of recreating a missing log), it is not unreasonable for a novice to hesitate long enough before doing so, to go from this question into a long and anxious search for an authoritative statement on the matter, having failed to get it here.